# Android app to let users complete tasks for cash

Tags: java, android

I am doing an android side project, and I was wondering if I could have my code reviewed to get feedback on improving its efficiency and overall elegance. Particular classes to focus on would be Dashboard, the two fragment classes.

Here is [Dashboard.java](https://github.com/jabrah29/Ask-Anyone/blob/ca73e3462aab9bd030509a5919e494167ceb84db/app/src/main/java/com/example/jacobabraham13/ubertask/UserFunctions/Dashboard.java), and [the rest of my code on GitHub.](https://github.com/jabrah29/Ask-Anyone/tree/ca73e3462aab9bd030509a5919e494167ceb84db)

```
 public  class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, AddTaskPgOne.OnFragmentInteractionListener , AddTaskPgTwo.FragTwoInterface{
    private Context context;
    private FloatingActionButton addTask;
    private UserDB userDB;
    private TaskDB taskDB;
    private static ArrayList<Task> tasks;
    private  static  RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private  static RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> inputData;
    private  static LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash_board);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
         inputData=new ArrayList<>();
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        context=this;
        addTask=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.addfab);

        userDB=new UserDB();
        taskDB= new TaskDB() ;
        tasks=new ArrayList<>();
        addTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startFragment("first");
            }
        });


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        taskDB.getData(this);
  //      feed = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.feedlist);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new CardAdapter(tasks);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);



        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setText("Recent Tasks");
        textView.setTextSize(25);

//        feed.addHeaderView(textView);
//
//        feed.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
//                                    long id) {
//
//
//            }
//        });


    }


    public ArrayList<Task> getTasks() {
        return tasks;
    }


    public static void setTask(ArrayList<Task> t){
        tasks=t;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(tasks.size()>0) {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void  populatefeed(ArrayList<Task> t){

        Collections.reverse(t);
        mAdapter=new CardAdapter(t);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

//        adapter.result= t;
//        feed.invalidateViews();
//        feed.setAdapter(adapter);


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dash_board, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                Bundle b= data.getExtras();


                String taskString=b.getString("task");
                Uri uri=Uri.parse(b.getString("uri"));
                List<String> items = Arrays.asList(taskString.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
                //Task task=new Task(items.get(0),items.get(1),items.get(2),items.get(3),items.get(4),items.get(5),items.get(6));

                if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(uri.toString())){
                    Log.i("here", uri.getEncodedPath());
                }
               // taskDB.addToDB(task);
                taskDB.getData(getApplicationContext());
            }

        }
    }//onActivityResult


    void startFragment(String label){
        switch (label){
            case "first":
                FragmentManager createTaskOne=getSupportFragmentManager();
                AddTaskPgOne addOne=new AddTaskPgOne();
                addOne.show(createTaskOne,label);
                break;
            case "second":
                FragmentManager createTaskTwo=getSupportFragmentManager();
                AddTaskPgTwo addTwo=new AddTaskPgTwo();
                //Bundle b=new Bundle();
                //b.putStringArrayList("first",inputData);
                addTwo.show(createTaskTwo,label);
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void dataTransfer(String[] data) {

        startFragment("second");
        inputData.addAll(Arrays.asList(data));

    }

    @Override
    public void onFragTwoInteraction(String[] data) {
        inputData.addAll(Arrays.asList(data));
        Log.i("done",inputData.toString());

    }
}
```

Comment: anyone willing to take a look??

Comment: Overall elegance of what? Code formatting? Cleverness to display 2 different fragments? Elegance of current solution?